# Why is my dryer squealing even after roller replacement and lubrication?

Tags: dryer

I have replaced my dryer rollers, but the rear right side (that was worn completely before replacing) is beginning to wear again and now causing a high pitched squeal.  The other rollers all seem to be fine.  The roller appears to lock up - if sprayed with WD40 it works fine for limited amount of time with no noise.  Also replaced both felt seals (Maytag Bravo Quiet Series Dryer).  Thoughts on next steps?

Comment: A) WD40 is _not_ a lubricant, use some appropriate grease for the rollers. B) How long ago did you replace the rollers? They will wear out again over time.

Comment: WD-40 _is_ a lubricant (as are water, saliva, and grape jelly). It's just not an appropriate one here. I'd expect bearings to be sealed units anyway (not requiring periodic lubrication).

Comment: JDNash, protocol is to post a model number, at least. Please do.

Comment: Valid point, @isherwood. Let me restate that: WD40 is neither a _good_ nor _long lasting_ lubricant.

Comment: Maytag MEDB400VQ0

Comment: The replacement kit for the rollers said no lubricant was required, which is why I did not use any.  WD40 was mainly to see if it helped the issue.  It did.  So, should I buy a special lubricant at this point for it or do I need a new bearing?

Comment: The rollers that were replaced had been on dryer since purchase - probably 9 years ago.  just replaced in the past month.  Replaced all rollers at the same time.  All rollers appear to be fine with the exception of the rear right again.

Answer (score 0):

Were the shafts clean? On dryers that I have replaced rollers there has been residue from the original roller. This residue increases the friction and may be the cause of your noise , the rollers I have replaced did not have bearings but were like a dense plastic with graphite impregnated they were not supposed to be lubricated if you have similar you might try cleaning with some isopropyl it sounds funny but a lubricant may cause problems in this application, if a lube is needed a grease would be more appropriate.

Comment: The shafts were clean and I wiped everything down in addition.  It said it did not require any lubricant.  The dryer was making a off balance noise, thudding, prior to taking out the rollers.  Changed all of the rollers and replaced front and rear felt seals.  Once back together it stated out great, no noise.  Then after use it began to have a slight squeal that seemed rhythmatic (hitting in same spot).  Now unless bearing is lubricated it is squealing all the time no longer just slight or rhythmatic.  I removed the back again today and can see that the roller is starting to wear again.

Answer (score 0):

1. As mentioned, check the roller *shafts*. Not only must they be clean, but any burr or nick can cause increased wear. Most shafts can be replaced in seconds by removing a single nut. Also verify that the shaft and roller are correctly assembled, with no missing or extra hardware.
2. Check dryer *level* and cabinet orthogonality. If the cabinet is untrue, or tilted (e.g. because a rubber foot fell off when moving the dryer), unnecessary strain is put on one pulley.
3. Check also the idler pulley, which is part of the belt tensioner. Again, if replacing the pulley, also replace the shaft or the whole arm -- the difference in price is slight, and the effort to service far outweighs the cost.